# Run 'vue-test-utils-karma-example' get Error: Can't resolve 'module' in '~\node_modules\_vue-server-renderer@2.5.13@vue-server-renderer'

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, karma-runner

[vue-test-utils-karma-example](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-test-utils-karma-example)

When I run this project

```
npm install
npm run test
```

logs as follow:

> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   8330:15-8333:9 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js  @
>   ./test/Counter.spec.js
>
> WARNING in
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   8335:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js  @
>   ./test/Counter.spec.js
>
> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in
>   'E:\bhtif\vue\vue-test-utils-karma-example\node_modules_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer'  @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/build.js
>   8276:19-36  @
>   ./node_modules/_vue-server-renderer@2.5.16@vue-server-renderer/index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js  @
>   ./test/Counter.spec.js
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

How can I solve this problem and why? Thanks!

Comment: This is related to this issue—[vuejs/vue-test-utils#440](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/440)

The fix will be in the next vue-test-utils release.